# Getting server error upgrading 2.5.5

Tags: upgrade

I'm upgrading from 2.5.2 to 2.5.5 and in the upgrade process everything went well until I tried to go from 2.5.4 to 2.5.5.  When I hit the link to upgrade to 2.5.5 I am now getting the following error:

= = =

Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://domain.com/admin.php?C=wizard&M=do_update&language=english&ajax_progress=yes. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

= = =

Has anyone come across this before?  Any advice greatly appreciated.  I can confirm that the server is up - it's just when I get this that I receive the error.

Comment: Is your third_party folder empty, or are there add-on folders still in it?

Comment: Have you tried temporarily blanking your `.htaccess` file? It is often the culprit in Internal Server Errors.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure this out.  Ultimately the issue was that there was a module still installed in the system directory when i was running the upgrade.  Was able to glean this bit of information by changing debug to 1 in the admin.php file and reloading it for the upgrade.  Once that was figured out I cleared out the rogue module and everything went normally.

Answer (score 2):

For me, temporarily renaming my system/expressionengine/third_party folder until the upgrade completed and then renaming it back worked.

Interestingly enough, the update script had updated the app_version variable in config.php to 254 before it failed (I was upgrading from 2.5.3).  Not sure if that helps anyone figure out where in the process it's failing, but I wonder if there's anything that the 254/255 part of the update which touches the third_party folder that's causing the failure.